# Is it faster to load a pickle dictionary or a file?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I have a `.txt` file with keys and values like this:

```
k1 v11
k1 v12
k1 v13
k2 v21
k2 v22
k3 v31
k3 v32
```

Each time I run my script I need to check if the given values are on that list.

I am considering preprocessing the `.txt` file to create a `dict` and save in a `pickle` file like this:

```
d = {
    k1: [v11, v12, v13],
    k2: [v21, v22],
    k3: [v31, v32],
}
```

Should it be faster to load such a dict or to read the original file?

I'd run the creation of the dict only once and than load it from the pickle.

Comment: If either is too slow, probably both are. Perhaps use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When to use csv / txt files**

- You need a format that is transportable across systems / languages.
- Your data is the output of a report which needs to be viewed by
  external applications.

**When to use pickle**

- You will be picking up pickle files from the same set-up that is exporting them: pickling is version-specific.
- You want to minimise the cost of repeatedly transforming data into a format Python can manipulate.
- Performance is important. Pickle files are serialised data, so they are efficient to read into Python.